# 1st time install of Ubuntu as dual boot on my Win 7 notebook now GRUB error?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

novice here, and I just installed Ubuntu as dual boot.  Now I just get the "rescue grub error"  and cant run either windows or Ubuntu.
I have no idea what to do despite reading the post here as some are complex.  can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

This post should help you out.  It's written for people in exactly your situation.

[DUAL BOOTING GUIDE PDF (WINDOWS AND LINUX)](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/dual-booting-guide-pdf-windows-and.html)